# Writing Ansible inventory file for one-off ansible play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing a one-off play to update some grok rule on my elasticsearch boxes (which I could be doing manually, but I anticipate doing a lot of these sorts of tasks so I want to get this working).

I simply want to run a lineinfile on 8 hosts:

```
#!/usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/myself/workingdir/hosts
- name: update those lines
  user: myself
  hosts: elasticsearch_hosts
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /opt/logstash/patterns/stuff
        regexp: STUFF_AND_THINGS
        line: STUFF_AND_THINGS [%{GREEDYDATA:big_h0nking_regex}\] ?.%{37_RANDOM_CHARACTERS:bologna} %{URIPATHPARAM:} %{*#&%$%@&@^$@:expletive}/%{NUMBER:some_more_crap}  %{NUMBER:minutes_wasted} %{[idk,lol]1776}
    - service: name=elasticsearch state=restarted
```

and here's my hosts file

```
192.168.1.98
192.168.2.76
192.168.3.54
192.168.4.32
192.168.5.10
192.168.6.123

[elasticsearch-hosts]
es-1 ansible_host=192.168.1.98
es-2 ansible_host=192.168.2.76
es-3 ansible_host=192.168.3.54
es-4 ansible_host=192.168.4.32
es-5 ansible_host=192.168.5.10
es-6 ansible_host=192.168.6.123
```

When this is run, I get:

```
PLAY [update them lines] ***************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

I know I'm not doing something correctly in the inventory file, but I'm not sure what since I've only ever used, for example, the rackspace rax module to build an inventory list when the play is run.

It may also be useful to note that es-1,,6 are short names I have defined on dns, so I can do, for instance `ssh es-1` and that works. It didn't seem to like those names on previous iterations of the file.

Comment: Voting to close because, as the answer points out, it's a simple typographic error.

Comment: @taskinoor has a good eye, but it didn't solve the issue. I am now receiving `[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available`.

Comment: To ensure there isn't a weridness inherent in your playbook, how about a simple `ansible all -m ping -i /home/myself/workingdir/hosts` to ensure it doesn't have any issues reading and parsing the hosts file.

Comment: Very odd; this is working. I was certain the issue was in the hosts file, and not the playbook. I'll take a closer look at paths in lineinfile, etc. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how I'm calling ansible-playbook.

```
#!/usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/myself/workingdir/hosts
```

This is not a proper way to pass an argument via shebang apparently, and as such ansible-playbook was defaulting to /etc/ansible/hosts, which is empty.